# How do I add an effective user name authentication property to Analysis Services Power BI dataflow entity?

Tags: powerbi

The Error:

This is the error I receive when adding the analysis services entity into the dataflow:

> Received error payload from gateway service with ID 896848: Internal
> error: MashupCredential for AS data source that uses Windows
> authentication needs to have an effective user name authentication
> property.

Steps Taken So Far:

1. I am copying the query from the advanced editor in Power BI Desktop and pasting it into a blank query as a new entity in the dataflow.
2. The query runs fine in both Desktop and published to the service.
3. I have used the Map User Names menu to map the UPN to an EffectiveUserName in the Power BI gateway (which was a prerequisite to refreshing in the service).